# Using Do While in a Multiplication App

Tags: vb.net, loops, do-while

I am editing a multiplication app in my VB class and I am setting up a calculation button to use a `Do While` statement to take what the user inputs and then display in a list box that number multiplied once per line (going from 1 to 9). Here is how my other function, using a For Next statement, looks when executed:

[image]

I need to emulate the same output when I code the `Do While` statement. Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub btnDoLoop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDoLoop.Click
    ' displays a multiplication table
    Dim number, product, count As Integer
    lstMultTable.Items.Clear()
    lstMultTable.Items.Add("Do Loop:")
    Integer.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, number)
    'Do Loop
    Do
        count = 1
        product = number * count
        lstMultTable.Items.Add("    " & number.ToString() & " * " & count.ToString() & " = " & product.ToString())
    Loop Until count = 10

End Sub
```

When I run this, my calculations are supposed to show in the list box, but it ends up locking up the program. Does anyone have any suggestions in regards to the `Do While` loop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are setting `count = 1` inside the loop so it will never ever exit.  that is probably supposed to be `count +=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count =1` should be before the loop. Inside theloop there should be `count = count + 1` (after the calculation).

Your loop now is an infinite loop because count is always 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Program works and I learned something as well.

Comment: Glad to help. If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that tge problem is solved.